# The Calendar setLenient method doesn't allow the check of the sanity of the year field

Tags: java

I used this method to check id a date entered by the user is valid or not:

```
  private boolean isThisDateValid(Date dateToValidate) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (dateToValidate == null) {
        return false;
    }

    cal.setLenient(false);
    cal.setTime(dateToValidate);
    try {
        cal.getTime();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that when the user writes a wrong year (big year) it doesn't throw an exception example : **12/09/2016666**

Should i check the sanity of the year field in a seperate method.

Comment: I don't understand. Is the `dateToValidate` in the year 2016666? Why would that be rejected? What do you think lenient means and what do you think `setLenient` does?

Comment: By default, the method setLenient() is set to true, you should always turn it off to make the date validation more strictly.

Comment: _you should always turn it off to make the date validation more strictly_ Where do you get that from? What do you think _validation_ means in this case?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if you set it to true, no validation will be done. I know that the setLenient method does not the validation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : Validation: if the month = 55 for example an error will be thrown ...

Comment: You can't construct a `Date` where the month will return as `55` so think twice about what you are doing here. Also, 55 obviously falls out of the month range. But what range exists for years?

Comment: every possible value of java.util.Date has a valid representation in the default calendar system.  This code literally does nothing but null check the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it is far from the present, 2016666 is still a valid year.  It's about 2 million years from now, so I can see why you might not want it in lots of contexts, but it would be strange for a date validator to suggest that it is not a legitimate date.  It would really be an incorrect behavior.

If you want to do additional validation (such as ensuring that the year field does not exceed the current year) you would need to do that yourself and throw the proper exception.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :))